# About writing to editor of a journal to identify serious mistake in a published article

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, errors-erratum

I am reading a paper published in a SCI-core journal.

After a very careful and tedious evaluation, I have come to the conclusion that the authors have made serious mistakes.

Should I write to the editor of the journal about it so that other people do not waste their time on this paper and may learn a thing or two about it? How can we do that?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_to_the_editor

Comment: Nops I did not read it earlier. Thanks for notifying me. If you share it as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Most wrong papers will not ever be used for anything.  Is there reason to think other people will make use of this paper?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Assuming you are have carefully checked that there really are serious errors, the best course of action would be to contact the authors of the paper first. Maybe they can explain subtle details, not clearly described in the paper, that explain everything. Of course it is important to be nice: It is very well possible that everything appeared to be correct with the knowledge at the time the paper was published. Or that it is you who misinterpreted the methods (possibly because the paper was a little vague). And even if there are errors: nobody is perfect. So please be nice.

It is possible that the authors wish to collaborate with you to correct the errors, leading to a shared publication: a win-win situation. I have seen this happen more than once.

If this does not work for some reason you can consider contacting the editor, who may or may not be interested in correcting the errors. That will be up to the editor.

Depending on your specific case, it may also be possible to do some experiments yourself and publish your findings, referencing the paper with the errors and correcting them.

However, if the errors are minor, the result is "unimportant", or you are not too sure that there really is a mistake that needs correcting, you could also decide to simply ignore the paper. There are plenty of bad and/or unimportant papers out there and frankly, they do not deserve the attention even if it is to correct mistakes.

Note: I have partly copied from [my own answer to a different, related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98833/do-i-point-to-mistakes-in-a-paper-if-i-cannot-contact-the-authors/98834#98834).

Comment: You begin your (good) answer by assuming 100% certainty.  I suppose that can actually happen once in a while.  In practice, and especially in my own experience, one can only be "mostly sure."  Most of the times I've been mostly sure of an error there actually was an error **of some kind**, but I think it would be more realistic to proceed from the premise of less than complete certainty.  If you have a serious concern that there is a serious error but are not completely sure, whether it is appropriate to ignore it really depends on the situation (I think).

Comment: You are right. I did not mean the 100% so literally but just wanted to emphasise that OP should check, and double check that there really is an error before taking action. I have edited my answer.

Comment: If Sjaffry follows this advice, it would be interesting to know the results achieved and time spent on this course of action. Hopefully, see you in a few months!

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on @anpami's sensible answer: in most fields of science we have a rotten publishing system which rarely corrects errors. Depending on the field, you can expect 20-80% of published papers to be false, only a small fraction of which are ever corrected. In a publish or perish world, authors and editors have strong incentives not to correct mistakes.

Correcting mistakes via the journal that publishes them is very slow and time-consuming: by the time a correction appears (if ever) most of the damage will be done. So you should look for other routes in order to quickly broadcast your opinon on that article.

The venue to do that depends on your field. PubPeer would be a possibility. In physics or mathematics you could write a comment as an Arxiv preprint. If the paper in question is on Biorxiv, you can directly write your comment there.

Comment: I agree that anpami and you correctly identify an existing problem in the publishing system, but the question was "should I write to the editor". The choice then is (1) No, and be part of the problem, or (2) Yes, and be part of the solution. I am not against leaving comments on a website, but it is much more polite (and useful) to contact the authors of the paper first, and then contact the journal together.

Comment: I agree with the arXiv suggestion, along with contacting the authors. In one occurrence, I spotted the same mathematical error in three independent papers and managed to [publish my analysis](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1340370554) of why the error was made and what was its impact, but this does not often happen.

Comment: @Louic : I do not know what the solution is, but trying to correct wrong papers one by one via journals is hopeless. (Too much work by orders of magnitude.) You do not reform a rotten system by following its rules, but by exerting external pressure.

Comment: I doubt that 20%-80% of published papers are *false* in any field.  They might contain errors but this does not make them false: the proof of a theorem might be flawed, but it doesn’t mean the theorem does not hold.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Then have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis . In some fields, only a minority of studies can be replicated, therefore the rest are wrong. And bear in mind that a replicable study can still be wrong in many other ways.

Comment: @ Mazurka Fahr: Thank you for sharing your experience. This reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisabeth_Bik , whose occupation is to detect photo manipulations in articles. As far as I understand, only a fraction of detected manipulations lead to corrections in journals.

Comment: @SylvainRibault I do not want to be overly strict about language but not being able to reproduce a result is not the same as suggesting the result is false.  Moreover, as the wiki article points out, this is “ affects the social sciences and medicine most severely”.  I get what you mean in the broad sense but suggesting a result is false because it cannot be reproduced is a bit of a stretch, unless you want to claim that medicine is equivalent to “most fields in science” (at least in the sense of the more “traditional” sciences *v.g.* physics, chemistry, geology etc,)

Comment: @MazurkaFahr it is NOT the job of the editor to *verify* the results: if anything it is unlikely to be technically possible.  As an extreme example, the editors of Phys.Rev. Letters cannot possibly reproduce results from LIGO or CERN.  Their job, however, is to make sure that the manuscript is properly vetted and assess the validity of any objection pre or post-publication.  Certainly they should make efforts to correct errors once these are brought to their attention, possibly by contacting again referees or assessors in the light of new information.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero : I focused on irreproducibility because we have data on the proportion of irreproducible papers in some fields. Other types of works have their own ways of being false. The career and publishing systems are however pretty much the same in most fields (with exceptions such as mathematics), and existing incentives do not encourage the production of good quality, reliable science.

Comment: @SylvainRibault For my part I do not wish to debate the quality of the work - I stand with you in observing the “Zeno-like” incremental nature of very many papers.  This does not make them *false*.  Moreover, while I decry the lack of reproducibility in some fields, and I look upon these works as likely to be subject to revisions, that does not make them *false* either although again no doubt some are likely pure fabrication (*v.g.* some recently retracted COVID studies).

Answer (score 2):

Editors may be reluctant to publish your letter. In that case, [PubPeer](https://pubpeer.com/) - which offers the possibility to write publicly available (critical) comments on research papers - may offer a good alternative.

Comment: I very much disagree with this answer. It the responsibility of a scientist to correct mistakes, regardless of who made them and why. If the errors are serious, something should be done about it to prevent others to continue building on this erroneous information. See also my related answer here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98833/do-i-point-to-mistakes-in-a-paper-if-i-cannot-contact-the-authors/98834#98834

Comment: You are depicting how the ideal situation *should* be, Louic. But in reality, editors are not always eager to publish critical comments or even to issue retractions. That's why PubPeer exists (and other similar platforms, e.g. Retraction Watch's blog).

Comment: That does not mean he should not write to the editor, although it would be preferable to contact the authors of the paper first. They may be very much interested in correcting the errors.

Comment: @anpami Do you have empirical evidence to your claim that editors are not always eager?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do is contact the authors. I expect that you'd want to be contacted if there was a potential issue with one of your papers! If they don't get back to you within about a week, it might make sense to contact the editor.

If you contact the authors, you may find that situation is not as bad as it seems:

1. Perhaps the paper's conclusions are correct, it's just that an implementation detail in the paper is wrong.
2. Maybe it just doesn't generalize to your use case e.g. due to differences in data preprocessing.

Remember, most papers are reviewed by the authors and their colleagues many times, in addition to being reviewed by editors and external reviewers. As a result, I think it's important to be respectful and report your findings in a clear and constructive way. If your findings have not been reviewed yet, you're asking the authors of the original paper to review your findings.

Finally, it may make sense to publish a paper or corrigendum on your conflicting results. This might be a substantial contribution to your field. You could also post a preprint on your preliminary results, e.g. to the arXiv, to raise awareness.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to contact the authors and politely ask for clarifications.  It could be a “simple” oversight at any point in the process.

If you are not satisfied with the answer, then the next step would be prepare a Comment describing the issue and submit this to the same journal for publication.  Presumably if your objections are *prima faciae* valid the editor would then contact the authors of the original paper for a reply, and the Comment plus rebuttal would then be published side by side if this clarifies the published paper.

The last option would be to publish this comment on arXiv or any such platforms.  In particular if the original erroneous manuscript was published on arXiv then sending the comment there would be the natural thing to do.  Doing this escalates the dispute to the public level and is often seen as agressive, especially if you have not tried to reach out to the authors first.